# React-router v5: Protected route will not render component or change browser URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've set up a `ProtectedRoute` component to send the user to a `NoAccess` component if they have read-only permissions. Most examples I've seen for protected routes involve returning a `Redirect`, which I did get working. However, I've been instructed not to do that, because that design requires declaring a `Route` for the `NoAccess` path in the `Switch` statement that a user could navigate to on their own.

So instead of returning `Redirect` I simply return a `Route`. But the URL of the browser never changes, and the component doesn't display. Is there something else I should be doing, or does this design simply not fit what I'm trying to do? Here's my class:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react';
import { useUser } from '../../context/userDataContext';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NoAccess from './NoAccess';

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  component: React.FC;
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ component, path, exact }) => {
  const { user, isReadOnlyUser } = useUser();

  if (user.loading) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    isReadOnlyUser ?
      <Route
        path='/app/protectedRoute/'
        component={NoAccess}
        exact
      />
      :
      <Route component={component} path={path} exact={exact} />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to render a bunch of duplicate `"/app/protectedRoute"` routes and then ***not redirect*** to the path so it can actually be matched and render the `NoAccess` component. I'm fairly certain either you've misunderstood a requirement, or whomever is giving you this specific requirement doesn't understand routing in general and how route protection works. Did the instruction mean to say that the `ProtectedRoute` should just render/return `<NoAccess />` directly in the case the user doesn't have access to the protected content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been instructed not to do that, because that design requires
> declaring a Route for the NoAccess path in the Switch statement that a
> user could navigate to on their own.

If the intent is to avoid explicitly rendering a route to redirect to, then I suspect you've misunderstood the requirement a bit by attempting to conditionally render one route path or the other. It doesn't make sense to conditionally render a bunch of routes to the same `"/app/protectedRoute"` path ***and not*** redirect the URL to it so the `NoAccess` component can be rendered.

My guess here is that it's intended the `ProtectedRoute` render directly the `NoAccess` component in the case the current user doesn't have access to the protected content.

Example:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react';
import { useUser } from '../../context/userDataContext';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NoAccess from './NoAccess';

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  component: React.FC;
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = (props) => {
  const { user, isReadOnlyUser } = useUser();

  if (user.loading) {
    return null;
  }

  return isReadOnlyUser
    ? <NoAccess />
    : <Route {...props} />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

If this `NoAccess` component needs access to any of the [Route Props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) then either decorate its export with the [`withRouter` HOC](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) or refactor the above code to pass them along.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ component, ...props }) => {
  const { user, isReadOnlyUser } = useUser();

  if (user.loading) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      component={isReadOnlyUser ? NoAccess : component}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: No, I didn’t misunderstand, but I think we may *all* be confused. What you have here makes perfect sense. I’ll try it in a bit and accept your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @CNDyson Hmm, gotta love incomplete and/or unclear business requirements. Thanks. If you happen to get a better understanding of the requirements and this answer isn't a good fit please update your post and ping me here and I can refine.

Comment: Your suggestion gets me closer. The `NoAccess` component now renders, but it does it 11 times on the page, which I think is the number of ProtectedRoute elements in the Switch of the parent component. Any ideas? I should have mentioned that React is way outside of my wheelhouse (I'm a Java dev), so I'm still gathering basics around routing.

Comment: @CNDyson Yeah, that's what my initial "It doesn't make sense to render a bunch of duplicate ...." comment was specifically referring to. That's exactly why you render one route for that specific content and the `ProtectedRoute` redirects to that route (*usually the login route, BTW*). Is the concern then that a user and also manually navigate to that route via entering its path in the address bar?

Comment: YES, that's exactly the concern. This is a public-facing site, and we don't want customers accidentally accessing the page and creating a bunch of tickets. That's how it was explained to me, anyway.

Comment: @CNDyson And no worries, it took me half an internship to effectively learn that React and OOP mix like oil and water, shifting from a CS background in C, C+/++, Java background and starting at ground zero in web development.

Comment: @CNDyson You can create another route protection component for the `"/app/protectedRoute"` that does the inverse of the `ProtectedRoute` component, e.g. if the user is a `isReadOnlyUser` user then the routed content is rendered, otherwise user is bounced off the route. Or you pass some route state when navigating to the protected route and bouncing them to `"/app/protectedRoute"` that if missing redirects them back, if they navigate there manually the state will be missing.  Does this make sense? I can edit and provide an example if necessary.

Comment: It does make sense! An UnprotectedRoute wouldn't need to be secure... That's perfect!! I can't thank you enough!! I *so* appreciate all of your help & patience.